# grunt exclude does not work

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, frontend

I'm using this object as my task config:

```
zip: {
  'front': {
    files: [
      {
        src: ['view/**/*.js', '!view/src'],
        dest: 'deploy/front.zip'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I expect that my front.zip output does not contain the path `view/src` but it does.
Here is my folder structure:

```
\
  dir1
  dir2
  dir3
  view
    src
    dist
    libs
  dir4
  dir5
  deploy
```

All I want to do is to compress all js files inside view but the ones inside src and put them in a compressed file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `!view/src/**` should do the trick.

Comment: would you put that as an answer?